# in array shift not work fine in returning

Tags: php

when i write code given below, working well

```
public  function Sidenews(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id <> 1 ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result_array=self::find_by_sql($sql);
        array_shift($result_array);
        return !empty($result_array) ? $result_array : false;
}
```

but when i try to write this code like given below it not working why ? can any one tell me

```
public  function Sidenews(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id <> 1 ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result_array=self::find_by_sql($sql);
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}
```

in this case i am facing that error,  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in .

Comment: Check [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) documentation, the function returns the shifted value not the array.

Comment: how come your not getting error in the first case?..Something is wrong in `find_by_sql($sql)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If your sql return ie. 3 rows, we have other results in above cases

**Case 1.**

```
$result_array=array(
     array('colum' => 'value1'), array('column' => 'value2'), array('column'=>'value3')
);
array_shift($result_array);
//now your result array is shorter, because first row was removed
var_dump(!empty($result_array) ? $result_array : false);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["column"]=>
    string(6) "value2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["column"]=>
    string(6) "value3"
  }
}
```

Explanation: you remove first row, check if result has more rows and return rest (set of rows)

**Case 2.**

```
//$result_array=self::find_by_sql($sql);
$result_array=array(
     array('colum' => 'value1'), array('column' => 'value2'), array('column'=>'value3')
);
var_dump(!empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["colum"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
}
```

Explanation: you check if there any rows and return first single row (not set, just single row)